# Can not inject HttpServletRequest object using @Context in jersey class in wildfly-8.2

Tags: cdi, java-7, wildfly-8, jboss-weld, jersey-1.0

I am using a jersey-1.19 in wildfly-8.2 with java 7. In one of the methods of the jersey class I am trying to inject HttpServletRequest using @Context annotation.
While accessing servlet request object I am getting following error:

```
The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:689) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:79) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.abc.rest.api.console.PollerAPI$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.pollGetKbaQuestions(Unknown Source) [abc-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185) [jersey-server-1.19.jar:1.19]
```

If I make my class "ApplicationScoped" then its working fine. But that doesn't make a feasible fix because I would want it to be request scoped.

Can anyone guide me on what could be the root cause of the issue? as well as what might be the solution?

Comment: How did you install Jersey? By default WildFly uses RESTEasy for it's JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: Actually, in my case we are migrating our code from jboss to wildfly and migrating to latest framework versions. So while migrating, I kept the same Jersey implementation and downloaded required dependencies.  For now, I have fixed this issue by making the component Application Scoped and It seems working. It won't cause any concurrency issues as Its stateless. Let me know If there is any way to bypass weld (CDI) while Jersey calls.

Comment: FWIW neither JBoss AS 7.x, JBoss EAP or WildFly use Jersey. There may be a way to replace the JAX-RS implementation, I'm just not sure how that's done.